# Converting Recursive Function to Tail Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am new Haskell and still trying to understand some of the basics. When writing recursive functions, I naturally write them in a recursive or tail recursive way without consciously selecting one over the other.

My question is:

1. Given any recursive function, is there an easy way to convert it to tail-recursive?
2. Given a tail-recursive function, is there an easy way to convert it to recursive?

Example Function

```
addOne [] = []
addOne (x:xs) = (x+1):addOne xs
```

Also, when writing a function, what is an easy way to tell if tail recursion is more appropriate over the alternative?

Comment: „Given a tail-recursive function, is there an easy way to convert it to recursive?“ – every tail recursive function is naturally recursive, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, but this has nothing to do with my question. Writing a function that is recursive vs. tail-recursive are two completely different programs (syntactically) that can accomplish the same task. So one can be converted to other.

Comment: @Mi: No, a tail-recursive function is always recursive and a function is not "completely different" from itself, neither syntactically nor in any other regard.

Comment: @Niklas B. I never said tail-recursive function isn't always recursive, not sure where you got that from. Also, tail-recursion is substantially different from non-tail recursion. If in doubt, do some reading before commenting, to avoid coming off as a pseudo intellect.

Comment: @Mi: Ah, now you are using the term "non-tail recursion" for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to Haskell as well. From what I have read, explicit recursion is frowned upon in the Haskell community. Rather, Haskell encourages programmers to use standard functions such as `map`, `filter`, `foldl`, `foldr`, etc. which encapsulates common recursive operations. For example,

```
addOne [] = []
addOne (x:xs) = (x+1):addOne xs
```

can be written as

```
addOne xs = map (+1) xs
```

or, going a step further using point-free style, as

```
addOne = map (+1)
```

There are likely situations where these standard functions don't fit easily and you have to write your own recursive function. However, I believe they cover 90% of the cases where you might be tempted to implement explicit recursion.

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but I hope it gives you some ideas to consider.

Answer (score 1):

> Given any recursive function, is there an easy way to convert it to
>   tail-recursive?

No.

> Given a tail-recursive function, is there an easy way to convert it to recursive?

Yes. Do nothing, and nothing remains undone (Lao Tse), as @Joachim Breitner already told you. But your definition of `recursive`seems to deviate from the common one, so maybe you tell us what you mean.

Comment: +1, for condescending useless answer.